# Twilio whatsapp integration

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

Is it possible to send/receive SMS from whatsapp using twilio number? Anybody tried twilio with whatsapp? I asked customer care, if it is possible, he said, not sure but many people asked about that.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Do you mean you want to sign up to Whatsapp using a Twilio number? Or send messages in Whatsapp using the Twilio API?

Comment: no, your cell number does not become registered to twilio ,you would need twilio wireless for that

Comment: @philnash, send/receive messages in Whatsapp using the Twilio API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else lands here, Twilio just released a WhatsApp integration via their new Business API

https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp

Comment: "Please note that if you use anything other than the official WhatsApp Business API or other official WhatsApp tools, we reserve the right to limit or remove your access to WhatsApp as this violates our policies. Please do not use any non-WhatsApp authorized third-party tools to communicate on WhatsApp." 

Dose twillio come under this.

Comment: Twilio is official. You will not get your account suspended

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Whatsapp do not have an API, so it is not possible to send or receive messages to Whatsapp using the Twilio API either.

If you are looking to send and receive messages to services like Whatsapp, then you might be interested in [Twilio Channels](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/channels). Channels are the various APIs that we are integrating into the one Twilio API so it's easy for you to send to all these third party services.

Channels lets you send and receive messages to services like:

- Facebook
- Slack
- HipChat
- Line
- SendGrid (for email)
- Twitter
- Amazon Alexa
- Viber

And will be supporting the following soon:

- WeChat
- Kik
- BBM

You can sign up for early access to Channels here: https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/channels

Comment: But is not possible to setup a virtual twilio number in a andoid virtual machine, and use the virtualized android envrironment to send whatstapp messages?

Comment: You could maybe do that. But it's not really using the Twilio API. It's probably against the Whatsapp terms too.